# SQL Error When Inserting Date Values into a Table: Conversion Failed from Character String

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, date-formatting

I'm encountering an error while trying to insert data into a SQL table, specifically into a DATE column. The dates are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD (e.g., 2010-01-12), but I keep receiving a conversion error.

Here's the error message:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The structure of the relevant table (BOOK) is as follows:

```
BookName (PK, VARCHAR(45), not null)
Genre (VARCHAR(25), not null)
DateOfPublication (DATE, not null)
NoOfPages (INT, not null)
WriterID (PK, FK, VARCHAR(11), not null)
EditorID (FK, VARCHAR(11), not null)
```

Here is an example of one of the insert statements that is causing the error:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK (BookName, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, WriterID, EditorID)
VALUES ('Valley of Heroes', 'Fiction', '2010-01-12',
```

I have tried different date formats but still encounter the same error.

How should I correctly format the DateOfPublication field in my insert queries to comply with the SQL DATE type?

Comment: can you put the result of 'EXEC sp_help BOOK' here, it will give the table details which will be helpful

Comment: you may be inserting wrong entry at in date column, maybe your order of data insertion is wrong

Comment: Your list column of columns is in the wrong order, to match your data it should be `insert into BOOK (BookName, NoOfPages, Genre, DateOfPublication, WriterID, EditorID)`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Dale. That's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've an error in your values list.
The value '10' should be at the end..

Your statement

```
insert into BOOK (BookName, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, WriterID, EditorID)
values ('Valley of Heroes','10','Fiction','2010-01-12',874,'20');
```

would try to add the value 'Fiction' into the DateOfPublication column.

To correct it use

```
insert into BOOK (BookName, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, WriterID, EditorID)
values ('Valley of Heroes','Fiction','2010-01-12',874,'10','20');
```

Comment: Thank you. that is was exactly what was wrong. I can't believe that I didn't notice this from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

*Always* list the columns when you do an `insert`.  The column names and values must be in the same order:

```
insert into book (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, , NoOfPages, EditorID)
    values ('Valley of Heroes', '10', 'Fiction', '2010-01-12', 874, '20');
```

Comment: Alright, I have to change the Query to include the column names but still getting the same error. I'm new at this so I'm sure its something very simple that I'm missing.